# Crashplan on headless ubuntu server to back to cloud?

Tags: 14.04, server, cloud, crashplan

I have a home server that acts as a backup server for all the computers in the house. It is running on headless ubuntu server 14.04.1 lts.

I want a viable online offsite backup solution for the contents of the server and am wondering if it would be possible to install crashplan on the server and configure it to backup the server contents to the cloud?

So far the instructions I have found, allow you set up your ubuntu server as the endpoint for other crashplan clients in the house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what plan you choose from Crashplan, you can backup everything else in the house to the Ubuntu server and then the entire Ubuntu server to the cloud in Crashplan, or you can back up multiple machines to each other in the house and to the cloud as well (also using Crashplan)

I got the Family plan which supports up to 10 computers so I do the latter.  I like that because I have local backups to take care of hardware failure scenarios, and cloud-based to take care of fire & theft scenarios.

Note: if you put only the one machine on Crashplan, I would backup everything else using a different method, maybe rsync or robocopy.  Crashplan won't back up Crashplan backups, for obvious reasons.